# Does PromQL have ternary operator or How to query on condition?

Tags: prometheus, alerts, promql

```
sum(process_open_fds) > bool max(process_max_fds)*0.9
```

If the above returns true, i would like to perform topk(10, process_open_fds). How can we have this both in a single query.

Tried like below - but no luck though

```
sum(process_open_fds) > bool max(process_max_fds)*0.9 > 1 and topk(10, process_open_fds)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  topk(10, process_open_fds)
and on ()
  sum(process_open_fds) > max(process_max_fds)*0.9
```

`and` returns the LHS, so you need it the other way around plus some grouping.